# How to customize <pagination-controls> visibility

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, pagination

I am using this "
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination" for pagination.

Working code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1f9hq.

Here i want to remove text "**Previous**" and "**Last**"  "**[image: screenshot]**".

I want to keep only arrow icons. And the selected page number box color also i want to change.
But I am not getting how to change this.
Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove these, just add **previousLabel=""** & **nextLabel=""** to your pagination-controls, which would now become

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"
    previousLabel=""
    nextLabel=""
    ></pagination-controls>
```

so you **app.component.html** would be:

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>ngx-pagination live demo</h1>
  <h4><small><a href="https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination">GitHub Repo</a></small></h4>
  <p>A bare-bones demo for your experimenting / bug-reproducing pleasure.</p>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>

  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event" previousLabel="" nextLabel=""></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add single quotations inside previousLabel and nextLabel: nextLabel=" ' ' ", without spaces

Comment: wow it is working like a charm. Thank you @AlqbalRaj. Can you please tell me how did you get to know this?

Comment: Ngx-pagination documentation has this as well as other options for pagination-controls... CSS didn't work because this being inside an iFrame

Comment: so I can't use CSS in this pagination?